# Populating a part of the site with dynamic content

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, codeigniter, populate

I am a newbie and have been programming this site for a school. And I have been stuck in a part where I have to show the logged in users the subjects he/she is currently enrolled in. I am thinking of making it appear using Ajax with a click of a menu button on the left side. So how do I populate this  with a card for each subject he/she is taking? The subjects is stored in a MYSQL database. I am currently using Codeigniter Framework. Would you suggest using scripts like Angularjs? I am very new to this. Here is the sample site:
[image]

Comment: There is already an open source software for school management from our Company. Please look at if you can use it and customize. But it is JSP based.

Answer (score 1):

If you are very new to this, I suggest you first use regular `GET/POST` based interactions with the site so that clicking on a button will reload this page, or a new one with the relevant information.

Once you have moved from total newbie to a novice/rookie, you can start converting some of those areas to `Ajax`.

Once you become fully comfortable with that, only then should you think using `JavaScript frameworks` like `angularjs` or `backbonejs`.

Its an incremental skillset acquisition, and is always best done like that.

All the best!

Comment: Actually, I have made a previous site using vanilla php. A friend of mine suggested using a framework. So I started learning Codeigniter. How do you think I should do it? I have a relational database to handle the subjects of each student.

Comment: @DirkJan using a framework is a very good idea! And CodeIgniter is a very simple, straightforward framework to get you started. I think you should concentrate this project solely on the ins and outs of `Codeigniter` & `mvc frameworks` in general. In the next iteration or another project, you should try using `Ajax/jQuery`. Its better not to put your fingers in all the jars at once..

Comment: Thanks for the tip. So let's focus on the framework and not minding the Ajax and other stuffs. In my experience in querying with multiple rows in a result, it is very iterative and code is very long and confusing. How do you suggest I should do it in the Codeigniter Framework?

Comment: @DirkJan the codeigniter documentation has everything you need! Read up the database class http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/ Go through it, try it, if you find issues SO is always there to help you! Best of luck